# Add Amplify Auth triggers from CLI without going through all CLI steps by (amplify auth update)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I need to add `Define auth challenge`, `Create auth challenge`, `Verify auth challenge response` triggers on my user pool and I have already setup my amplify a while ago. Now I search a lot but didn't find the solution to add triggers directly, what I found every where is `amplify auth update` and go through all CLI steps, which I don't want to do.

There is one way by adding them via AWS Console but then if I push anything with `amplify push` it wipes all the custom triggers.